App Exchange Security review
I am having a big blocker question over App Exchange security review. While publishing our App to the AppExchange, and when we scheduled a security review ...
Is security team of AppExchange will also review and consider the Quality issues of our salesforce code while publishing our app? Because, I ran checkMarx scan over my Salesforce code, it reports few of Quality issues like 'DML statements inside loops'...etc...
I already gone through the articles on how the security review happens and something something....But they didn't clarified me about this question.
I would appreciate and glad to the detailed explanation.

We have various cases where there are false positive "best practice" violations, including SOQL in loop, that we have never had any security review issues with and that we do not include in our false positives documentation. I.e. these have not been a cause for issue during security review. That said, we have always ensured to comment in the code as to why we violate "best practice" when we do.

Here is my update on the question i posted....The AppExchange security team only validates the security issues which may provide risk to the customer attributes and data.
we recently published our app along with the Quality issues of code , they just suggested to follow best practices and if not , provide comments along the code of line representing why we not followed best practice for that along with our requirement to not followed that.
Thanks...
